# How to click in a select element with several options with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, select, cypress, ui-automation, select-options

I have a problem in clicking in a select element using cypress.
This is the element to click:
[image]

And i receive this error.
`cy.click()` cannot be called on a `<select>` element. Use the `cy.select()` command instead to change the value.

This is my code:

```js
cy.get('[name^=shopveg]').click()
```

After searching some people advise using the trigger command.
Changed the code to:

```js
cy.get('[name^=shopveg]').trigger('click')
```

The step pass in the cypress execution but the click was not executed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you just want to see the options on the screen? Are you trying to select an option?

Comment: The error message you are getting doesn't sound like a correct error message. Do you have a screenshot to prove the wording?

Comment: @agoff I want to validate the options in the menu and also be able to click in one of them. For example Bananas

Answer (score 4):

Given the select looks like a "special" implementation, i.e a web component with slots, you may need to click it open to see the option values (lazy loading).

If so, try with [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin

**Install**

```js
npm install cypress-real-events
// or
yarn add cypress-real-events
```

**In /cypress/suport/e2e.js**

```js
import "cypress-real-events";
```

**Test**

```js
cy.get('[name^=shopveg]')
  .should('have.value', '1')         // confirm initial value
  .realClick()                       // click open

cy.contains('option', 'Batatas')     // this option exists
cy.contains('option', 'Arroz')       // this option exists 
cy.contains('option', 'Bananas')     // this option exists
// etc

cy.get('[name^=shopveg]')
  .select('Bananas')                 // select new option
  .should('have.value', '3')         // confirm new value
```

Answer (score 3):

As the message says, `.select()` is the command to use

```js
cy.get('[name^=shopveg]').select('Bananas')
```

That's because `<select>` behavior is implemented by a web component (see `slot` tag), not javascript, so there's no click handler available.

Answer (score 1):

To validate the values in the select menu, you can iterate through them with `cy.each()`.

```js
const options = [ "Batatas", "Arroz", "Bananas", "Tomates", "Macaz" ];
cy.get('[name^=shopveg]').find('option').each(($el, index) => {
  cy.wrap($el).should('have.text', options[index]);
});
```

As @Grainger answered, you can then use `cy.select()` to pick a value.